# How to shift a math formula to the left in {eqnarray}?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I think my question is clear from pictures. Pictures are  output and its [latex code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnGGQ.png)  .

[image]

Comment: Should the location `Here` also be covered by the left brace?

Comment: No it is outside of brace. Actually the upper term is equal to the brace term, but since the brace-term is too long I have to write them in two separate lines  @Werner

Comment: Please avoid posting code in the form of images. Rather post the code itself.

Comment: Are there two different inner products (one with parentheses and bar, one with angle brackets and comma)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [avoid `eqnarray`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764) and use the proper math notation using `cases`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & \mathrm{d}^2 g(F(\bar{x}) \mid \lambda) (\nabla F(\bar{x}) \omega) \\
  & \qquad = \begin{cases}
    \mathrm{d}^2 g(F(\bar{x})) (\nabla F(\bar{x}) \omega 
      & \text{if $\mathrm{d} g(F(\bar{x})) (\nabla F(\bar{x})) \omega = \langle \lambda, \nabla F(\bar{x}) \omega \rangle$} \\
    \infty & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your help. Your second code doesn't work in my system at all. I'll figure it out

Comment: @Redshoes: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: it says "File not found" when I want see output !

Comment: @Redshoes: So it compiles without problem? You just can't view the output using your editor? Strange.

Comment: ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.384 \end{align*}
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
19057 strings out of 493323
379991 string characters out of 3138196
473190 words of memory out of 3000000
22224 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
11027 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
211i,19n,67p,1240b,399s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: @Redshoes: I can't replicate the problem. Possibly because I don't have the `align*` environment on l.384 of my document...

Comment: Why not `multline`?